# Moving tkinter objects leaves a ghost trail

Tags: python, python-3.x, animation, tkinter

I try to move a bunch of objects. Their position is updated by `onMouseMove`. Moving the objects even just a little bit faster will leave a clear ghost trail. Could anyone suggest something on how to avoid the ghost trail? 
**Here is my code:**

```
def onCanvasLeftMouseDown(self, event): 
    self.mIsCanvasLeftMouseDown = True
    self.mOnMouseDownX = event.x
    self.mOnMouseDownY = event.y

def onCanvasMouseMove(self, event):
    self.mMouseX = event.x
    self.mMouseY = event.y
    if (self.mIsCanvasLeftMouseDown):
        self.mMouseMoveLimiter = self.mMouseMoveLimiter + 1

        if (self.mMouseMoveLimiter > 10):  
            self.mMouseMoveLimiter = 0

            difX = self.mMouseX - self.mOnMouseDownX
            difY = self.mMouseY - self.mOnMouseDownY

            for panel in self.mPanelList:
                baseX = panel.initalX
                baseY = panel.initalY
                panel.x = baseX + difX
                panel.y = baseY + difY

def onCanvasLeftMouseUp(self, event):
    self.mIsCanvasLeftMouseDown = False
```

I have also tried using an animate function and calling after, "after(1, self.animate)". However, it got even worse, so i decided to leave the animation code inside the `onMouseMove`.

Please note the `Panel` object is in fact a `canvas` with 3 `Tkinter Text`children widgets. The parent(`Master`) for the `canvas` inside the `Panel` object is another big `canvas` which is also my background.

**Just to be thorough** here is the main part of Panel class code:

```
class TATDPanel:
    def __init__(self, master, node):
        self.mCanvas = Canvas(self.mMaster, width=self.mCanvasWidth, height=self.mCanvasHeight, bg='gray') 

        self.mFormTextBox = Text(self.mCanvas, width=self.mFormTextBoxWidth, height=self.mFormTextBoxHeight)
        self.mFormTextBox.tag_configure("center", justify='center')


        self.mUPosTextBox = Text(self.mCanvas, width=5, height=0.6)
        self.mUPosTextBox.tag_configure("center", justify='center')

        self.mIndexTextBox = Text(self.mCanvas, width=3, height=0.6)
        self.mIndexTextBox.tag_configure("center", justify='center')
```

**Update 01:**
Here is a dropbox link to the whole project, the link will only work for 1 day.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/yi9ja9zkqo9xcjy/Dependency%20Parsing.rar?dl=0

Comment: @stovfl I did what you suggested but it didn't help, its super laggy and ghosty, i feek like i might have missed something important, any other suggestion ?

Comment: @stovfl I edited the MoveMove code and i also shared the Panel code just to be safe and thorough, Thanks.

Comment: @stovfl `createKeyFrame` is for saving the `x` and `y` position, i removed all the extra codes including the `createKeyFrame`  so you don't get distracted by it, the events are bound to a `Canvas` which is my background a clear white background which `panel` is created on this background.

Comment: @stovfl I added a dropbox link that refers to the whole project, you can download it.

Comment: Couldn't reproduce your issue, assume low grafik power. Try in `class TATDPanel` `invalidateUI(self, textBox=False):` and move `.delete/.insert/.tag_add` inside `if textBox:` block. Change in `.__init__(...` to `self.invalidateUI(True)`. **Second**: Why do you `TATDPanel(self.mMaster` instead of `TATDPanel(self.mBackGroundCanvas` and only do `.mBackGroundCanva.place(...`?

Comment: @stovfl Interesting, because my PC is fairly powerful one, so it must be some kind incompability or maybe a bug?, but i will try to improve `invalidation` so it only invalidates the data it should, in the end if i can pin point the problem i will update the post later, thanks for the help